# How to get an enriched property in the output message when using Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I'm trying to output an enriched property into the rendered message using Serilog:

```
private static Tester GetTester()
{
    return new Tester {Count = 7, Name = "Redmond"};
}

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Site", "Dan Local")
    .WriteTo
    .ColoredConsole()
    .CreateLogger();

var tester = GetTester();

Log.Verbose("{Site} - This is verbose {@tester}", tester);
Log.Verbose("This is verbose {@tester} - {Site}", tester);
```

The first log statement outputs:

```
2014-08-19 10:02:25 [Verbose] "SeriLogTest.Tester" - This is verbose {@tester}
```

The second log statement outputs:

```
2014-08-19 10:02:25 [Verbose] This is verbose Tester { Count: 7, Name: "Redmond" } - "Dan Local"
```

I would expect them both to output the same information, just in a different order as defined by the message template.  But as you can see, if you don't put the enriched property last, it is taken over by the provided object to be logged and the second template property is ignored.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Output templates are the way to achieve this, i.e.:

```
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole(
      outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm} [{Level}] {Site}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

This will print the value of the `Site` property along with every message; e.g.:

```
Log.Information("Hello");
```

Prints:

```
19:40 [Information] Dan Local: Hello
```

Comment: How would you set this in the appSettings?

Comment: How do you achieve this if the sink you're using doesn't support overriding/specifying output templates? (I'm using the Azure Table Storage sink.)

Comment: @alastairs usually the ones without `outputTemplate` support aren't outputting formatted text; may need more info about where you intend the formatted text to go (another question?). Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone who stumbles across this is curious about how to output *all* the available context properties, you can use `{Properties}` in the output string.

```
.WriteTo.ColoredConsole(
  outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm} [{Level}] {Properties}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

Prints:

```
19:40 [Information] {Site="Dan Local"}: Hello
```