# How are Serilog-enriched properties written to Azure Table Storage sink?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-table-storage, serilog

Following up to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385664/how-to-get-an-enriched-property-in-the-output-message-when-using-serilog/25422546?noredirect=1#comment67922768_25422546).

I've added Serilog to an Azure Service Fabric application and am using the [Azure Table Storage sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage) as a stop-gap solution to something more production-grade. I'd like to enrich my log messages with information from the Service Fabric context/environment and have written an enricher to achieve this. I can see it the enricher being called while debugging, but I see none of the additional properties written to my tables. I'm not sure whether I should expect to see the properties as additional columns in the table, or included in the log messages themselves, but I don't see either. Additionally, I've not mentioned the additional properties in my log messages as I expect them to be included by default, although perhaps I've missed a configuration step.

Answer (score 1):

After much more digging around, I've found that the enriched properties are being written to the `Data` column in Azure Table Storage, which is JSON formatted.